# ViewPager выходит за нижнюю границу экрана

Tags: android, xml

Создаю приложение, используя стандартный шаблон приложения с вкладками. Возникает проблема - блок, в котором вставляется, с использованием `Fragment'ов`, содержимое вкладки (`ViewPager`) выходит за нижнюю границу экрана, несмотря на то, что установлен атрибут `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: может просто содержимое не влезает на экран?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант для корректной прокрутки дочерних элементов `CoordinatorLayout` использование `NestedScrollView` из библиотеки совместимости версии 4 вместо `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть в том, что вы используете координатор лаяут, который грубо говоря рамок не имеет, и используете вкладки, кторые должны скрываться например или еще что-то, так вот вы ставите высоту вьюпейджера по высоте координатор лаяута, а его на высоту вкладок сдвигает вниз.

Comment: Да, думаю Вы правы буду пробовать копать в этом направлении